# Is this possible to brute force 25 billions billions password in less than a month?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

i'm using Hashcat for a while & try to solve this challenge: is this possible to crack at least half the possibilities combinations password of 10 character using 94 characters from keyboard with md4 hashing. I calculated & there 53,861,511,409,489,970,176 combinations, there was a service that offer using [2petaflops](https://www.ais.cmc.osaka-u.ac.jp/en/uncategorized/octobus-installation2/) supercomputer for free, how fast would it be if i run on it?

Comment: Depends how long the supercomputer actually takes to calculate a hash (or, possibly more usefully, how many hashes it can compute in a second) - they aren't always heavy on floating point operations (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/do-cryptographic-hashing-algorithms-operate-only-on-integers)

Comment: That's about 10000 billions hashs per seconds. So far, [single computer seems to go to 50G/s](http://thepasswordproject.com/oclhashcat_benchmarking) with some old hardware, so you would need like 200 computers like this in parallel. [Another more recent benchmark](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) shows 350G/s so now, find 30x more GPUs or get 30 computers like that.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this site that pretty much ask for the same but with different numbers (and with a different "super computer") in mind. Take [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+long+brute+password+created%3A3y..1d) search query and have fun.

Comment: Nothing a few dozen recent GPUs can't handle.

Comment: @Overmind can you suggest some GPU model for this?

Comment: Any High End Radeon manufactured in the last years (anything since 5870 forward (and above at performance) but preferably RX580/570 or Vega) or the 1070/1080 series (even 1060 can do relatively good). A good performance reference is for the card to have at least 2tflops processing power (which all mentioned ones have).

Comment: In 2012, you could do 63 billion guesses against SHA1 or 180 billion combinations per second against MD5 on a moderate budget.

By scaling your cluster to 25 AMD Radeon graphic cards, the number would go up to 350 billion guesses per second ([source](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and it can even be done relatively fast.

Any High End Radeon manufactured in the last years (anything since 5870 forward (and above at performance) but preferably RX580/570 or Vega) or the 1070/1080 series (even 1060 can do relatively good). A good performance reference is for the card to have at least 2T-FLOPs processing power (which all mentioned ones have).

If we take the example of the minimum I stated: Radeon 5870 - near full processing power will try the number of combinations you stated (53E) in approx **283 days**. A 1060 half that. One RX580 1/3 that (<95 days). 4xRX580 can do it in under 25 days.

If you use more cards you get less time.

And since 2 TerraFLOPs can do it in 283 days, 2 PetaFLOPs (that you mentioned as a service) can do it in 0.276 days - aka **under 7 hours**.

Note: the above assumes a good software is used that can take advantage of near the full processing power of a card.

Note 2: For only half of your stated value, of course, only have the specified time will be required.

Comment: Side note: it's often easy to parallelize a brute force shared across identical hardware by well choosing you pattern (62 parallel computers running a `[a-zA-Z0-9]` brute force can be parallelized by setting the 1st character for each of them)

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to manually allocate tasks across multiple hardware devices.